# backboneJS how to handle non model [probably?] data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am a newbie to backbone and started using it just over a month ago.  In my application's view I have to load a list of countries, so as to allow user to select a country.

Currently, I am treating the country list as part of regular HTML markup data and losing in the form load i.e document ready event.  I am creating models and views for other data that I manage which is critical to my application.

I want to know if this approach is correct.  Or alternately, Should I treat *all data* as models or collections or whatever and render them in that way?

Thanx for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is not the best way to load the html page and then hitting server again by backbone fetch. For that, you can use html templates to populate fields in the page. But, if you have to interact with and re render the list, for example each list's remove button removes the country from the list and re render the list in order, backbone is the best option.

Comment: countries list is typically huge data. Even though its static information, I am currently loading on ready event. 
$(function() {
  loadCountries();
});

So, this is anyway a separate ajax call. Is it good to load via Model/collection?

Comment: If you don't need backbone for this page, other than fetching, don't use backbone as we use it only for a fetch. But if you have user interactions on this page, backbone collections/models are a cleaner and good way.